# How to get fields from multiple odoo modules on one single report?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8, qweb

I am creating a new report in MRP module and I want to get some fields from other modules like product, purchase, point of sale, etc.
So , I am successfully getting fields from MRP module using object name mrp.production. Now, How can I call other fields from other modules on the same report?

Is it possible by using Qweb only or I need to create an Inheritance and then make a change in Qweb?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a model from a SQL View (with all data that you need). You can check an example in the `project_report.py` in the project module. That shows pretty well how to create models from views.

You can also create a postgresql view model with the data that you need, check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252030/add-the-new-dynamic-field-in-odoo?answertab=votes#tab-top)