# Add the new Dynamic Field in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Is it possible to add new field based on View in Postgresql in Odoo without using Odoo model class file. ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Could you explain it better?

Answer (score 1):

You can get have a model getting it's data from a view. In fact that's widely used by reports.

But the field list available needs to defined in the model.

Comment: Is there any way to create above mentioned model dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

for creating dynamic views in odoo, you better refer this
[link](http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/sales-analysis-report)

**Here is the solution**

- Specify the parameter _auto=False to the OpenERP object, so no table corresponding to the _columns dictionary is created automatically.
- Add a method init(self, cr) that creates a PostgreSQL View matching the fields declared in _columns.

**Python code:**

```
class xyz(osv.osv):
_name = "xyz"
_description = "xxx"

_auto = False

_columns = {
            'unique_id': fields.char('Employee ID', size=12),
            'employee_id': fields.many2one('table3', "Name"),
        }

def init(self, cr):
    openerp.tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'table_preview')
    cr.execute("""
        create or replace view payslip_preview as (
                    SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT ps.id as id, emp.unique_id as unique_id, emp.id as employee_i
                    FROM table1 psl 
                    JOIN table2 ps ON (ps.id = psl.slip_id) 
                    JOIN table3 emp ON (emp.id = ps.employee_id) 
                   WHERE ps.state IN (''draft'') ORDER BY 1',
                    'SELECT id FROM table4 ORDER BY sequence') AS 
                    (
                        "id" int,
                        "unique_id" varchar(10),
                        "employee_id" int,
                    )
            )
        """)
```